# "Version string portion was too short or too long" when opening Visual Studio project in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I try to open solution from VS 2012 in Xamarin Studio Community but one of projects - asp.net mvc project - gives "Version string portion was too short or too long"

.net version is ok I think.

I tried to create simple asp.net mvc project in VS and then open it in XS and everything went fine. So I don't know what is wrong in this case.

I found a solution that deleting the lines

`VisualStudioVersion = {0}`

`MinimumVisualStudioVersion = {0}`

works with that, but not in my case.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was this entry in the .csproj file:

```
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, 
    processorArchitecture=MSIL"><HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
```

After replacing "**MvcPagesVersion**" for "5.2.3.0" it worked just fine.